# Как изменить вид вывода сообщения?

Tags: python, aiogram, google-spreadsheet, pygsheets

Всем привет. Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли каким то образом добавить **:00** к числу, например в таблице 8-17, а нужно чтобы был вид 8:00 - 17:00. Ситуация: Есть телеграмм бот, который получает данные из ячейки гугл таблицы и при отправке сообщения боту (Например: Дата 12.12) он присылает из таблицы значения. Скрины прикрепил.

Хендлер на отправку сообщения:

```
@dp.message_handler(filters.Regexp(regexp=r"(((Д|а)та)(\s)(\d+))"))
async def raspisanie_handler(message_from: types.Message) -> None:
   user_id: str = str(message_from.from_id)
   command, number = get_command_number(message_from.md_text)

   values = bot._google_table.search_raspisanie(number)
   if values == -1:
      message = 'Такой даты не существует, либо его нет в расписании '
   else:
      adel = values[0]
      leysan = values[1]
      rasilya = values[2]
      message = f' Адель {adel}\n Лейсан {leysan}\n Расиля {rasilya}'
   try:
      await message_from.reply(message)
   except Exception as send_error:
      logging.debug(f"{send_error.message}: Trouble id: {user_id}")
      return
```

Функция:

```
def search_raspisanie(
    self,
    data: List[List[Union[str, bool, float, int]]],
    search_data_row = 2,
    adel_row = 4,
    leysan_row = 5,
    rasilya_row = 6
):
    googlesheet_client: pygsheets.client.Client = self._get_googlesheet_client()
    wks: pygsheets.Spreadsheet = self._get_googlesheet_by_url(googlesheet_client)
    try:
        find_cell = wks.find(data, matchEntireCell=True, rows=(search_data_row, search_data_row))[0]
    except:
        return -1
    find_cell_col = find_cell.col
    adel_rows = wks.get_value((adel_row, find_cell_col))
    leysan_rows = wks.get_value((leysan_row, find_cell_col))
    rasilya_rows = wks.get_value((rasilya_row, find_cell_col))
    return [adel_rows, leysan_rows, rasilya_rows]
```

[image: Сообщение в тг]
[image: Вид из таблицы]

Comment: print('-'.join((f'{x}:00' for x in '8-17'.split('-'))))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для этого можно воспользоваться модулем `re`:

```py
import re

text = '7-19' # Исходная строка
text = re.sub(r'(.+)-(.+)',r'\1:00-\2:00',text)
# Находим по шаблону xx-xx, и переводим в xx:00-xx:00
print(text) # 7:00-19:00
```

В вашем же случае нужно заменить:

```py
adel = re.sub(r'(.+)-(.+)',r'\1:00-\2:00',values[0])
leysan = re.sub(r'(.+)-(.+)',r'\1:00-\2:00',values[1])
rasilya = re.sub(r'(.+)-(.+)',r'\1:00-\2:00',values[2])
message = f' Адель {adel}\n Лейсан {leysan}\n Расиля {rasilya}'
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Всё как нужно.